# Regex URL parsing with Youtube and non Youtube links

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url, youtube

Hi my problem today is in using Regex to parse urls.  I want to first convert any youtube url's into embedded videos and then convert the remaining urls (just regular links) into a href links. I've gotten both of these to work, my problem is after I've gotten the youtube url's converted the second regex replace messes up the youtube videos, so what i need for it to do is ignore the iframe tags ideally.  I'll be the first to admit I am horrendous at regex so I would really appreciate a little help, I think it won't be too difficult for someone half-decent with regex.

Cheers,
Jordan

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function linkifyYouTubeURLs() {

    //replaces youtubeurls with iframe
    var re = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[?=&+%\w-]*/ig;
    document.getElementById('CPH_Main_postContent').innerHTML = document.getElementById('CPH_Main_postContent').innerHTML.replace(re, '<br><iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0"> </iframe><br>');

    //replaces urls with links
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    document.getElementById('CPH_Main_postContent').innerHTML = document.getElementById('CPH_Main_postContent').innerHTML.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do this in one pass and use function as a replacement:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function linkifyURL (match, offset, string)
{
    var re =/https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[?=&+%\w-]*/ig;

    var m = re.exec (match);
    if (m)
    {
        return '<br><iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + m[1] + '" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>';
    }
    else return '<a href="' + match + '">' + match + '</a>';
}

function linkifyYouTubeURLs () 
{
    var element = document.getElementById ('CPH_Main_postContent');

    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace (/\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/ig, linkifyURL);
}
// -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="CPH_Main_postContent" onload="linkifyYouTubeURLs();">
    <p>This is youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUcD9YIAqJE</p>
    <p>This is normal link: http://www.google.com/</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great thank you very much Mikhail, that solved it perfectly!  You're a life-saver, wish I could buy you a beer!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, your problem is that the second replacing replaces youtube links also.

To ensure that only non-youtube links are replaced, use a negative lookahead in the second regex as:

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/(?!(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com).*)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
```

The negative lookahead ensures that the following part doesn't match youtu.be/ or youtube.com followed by zero or more characters